# Imported DLL doesn't give me access to any of the classes

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have created a class library with the following:

[image]

I then referenced the DLL into my project and when I click on it to explore what classes I have accessible to me, I see this:

[image]

as you can see there are no classes accessible, there's nothing. So I cannot go into controllers and add a new one because technically I have no models or context class....

Thoughts?

**Example of what a model class looks like:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace UFACoreLibrary.Models
{
    class LocationAssignment
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int locationId { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int typeId { get; set; }

        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thats an example of what one of the classes in the core library looks like, in case its a code issue.

Also All I am doing is building the project and using the DLL generated.

Comment: Could it be because you didn't make your classes `public`?  E.g. `public class LocationAssignment`, rather than `class LocationAssignment`.

Comment: Yes that was the case - I didnt realize they have to be public.... >.> IMO they should be public by default

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure before if this was the problem, but since it's so, I'll add a real answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, by default Visual Studio will not add the keyword `public` to classes it fills in when you use the wizard.  You'll need to add `public` to make the classes visible outside the assembly (e.g. `public class LocationAssignment`).